# complex number addition and using copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, complex-numbers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
    float real,imag;
public:
    
    complex(complex &c)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        real=c.real;
        imag=c.imag;

    }
    void showData()
    {
        count<<"the sum is"<<endl;
        cout<<real<<"+i"<<imag<<endl;
    }

    complex addition(complex x,complex y)
    {
        complex temp;
        temp.real=x.real+y.real;
        temp.imag=x.imag+x.imag;
        return temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    complex c2(2,3),c3(c2),c1;
    c2.showData();
    c3.showData();
    c1=c1.addition(c2,c3);
    c1.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to add the complex number by passing the value from object and replicating the same value using complex number. This is the error I am getting:

```
Error:C:\Users\Santosh\Documents\cplusplus\complex_addition.cpp|48|error: no matching function for call to 'complex::complex()'|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define two constructors for the `complex` class to solve it:

```
complex() {}
complex(float rl, float im) : real(rl), imag(im) {}
```

The value were never initialized since there were no constructors given to put 2 & 3 in `real` & `imag` respectively. The class object `c1` will require `complex() {}` constructor.

Comment: worked by making another parameterized constructor. thank you.

Comment: @user8626250 both constructors are required and necessary to run the program correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
    float real,imag;
public:
    complex()
    {
        cout<<"default constructor"<<endl;
        real=0;
        imag=0;
    }
   complex(float r, float i)

    {
    cout<<"parameterized construction";
    real=r;
    imag=i;
    }
    complex(complex &c)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        real=c.real;
        imag=c.imag;

    }
    void getData()
    {
        cout<<"the complex number are: "<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"i"<<endl;

    }
    void showData()
    {
        cout<<"the sum is: ";
        cout<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"i"<<endl;
    }

    complex addition(complex x,complex y)
    {
        complex temp;
        temp.real=x.real+y.real;
        temp.imag=x.imag+x.imag;
        return temp;

    }
};



int main()
{
    complex c2(2,3),c3(c2),c1;
    c2.getData();
    c3.getData();
    c1=c1.addition(c2,c3);
    c1.showData();


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler thinks `complex c2(2,3)` is trying to invoke the '()' operator. You haven't defined a constructor that takes two ints.

Comment: I think you will find the OP was missing a default constructor.